# cometd bayeux client can't get subscribed acknowledgement?

Tags: groovy, cometd

Actually i am running cometd-demo server in my local using maven jetty run shown in the doc https://docs.cometd.org/current/reference/ and trying to subscribe and publish something in a `broadcast channel`. Using Groovy script shown below,

```
ClientSessionChannel.MessageListener mylistener = new Mylistener();  

def myurl = "http://localhost:8080/cometd/"

MyHttpClient httpClient = new MyHttpClient();

httpClient.start()

Map<String, Object> options = new HashMap<String, Object>();

ClientTransport transport = new LongPollingTransport(options, httpClient);

BayeuxClient client = new BayeuxClient(myurl, transport)

println 'client started on URL : '+ client.getURL()


client.handshake ( new ClientSessionChannel.MessageListener() {

    public void onMessage(ClientSessionChannel channel, Message message) {
        if (message.isSuccessful()) {   
            println 'Handshake Message : ' + message 
        }
    }
})

boolean handshakecheck = client.waitFor(1000, BayeuxClient.State.CONNECTED);

println 'Handshake check : '+ handshakecheck

    client.batch( new Runnable() {

        public void run() {

            client.getChannel("/foo/hello").subscribe(

                    new ClientSessionChannel.MessageListener() {

                        public void onMessage(ClientSessionChannel channel,
                                              Message message) {
                                println "subscribed : "+ message
                        }
                    })
        }

    });
```

The program Output :

```
client started on URL : http://localhost:8080/cometd/
Handshake Message : [minimumVersion:1.0, clientId:fv0ozxw8cb5e11vtlwpacm7afp, supportedConnectionTypes:[websocket, long-polling, callback-polling], advice:[reconnect:retry, interval:0, maxInterval:10000, timeout:20000], channel:/meta/handshake, id:1, version:1.0, successful:true]
Handshake check : true
```

Here I can't get the `subscribed` message as in the code. But in server log It prints like shown below,

```
2018-02-12 20:30:32,687 qtp2069584894-17 [ INFO][examples.CometDDemoServlet] Monitored Subscribe from fv0ozxw8cb5e11vtlwpacm7afp,last=0,expire=0 for /foo/hello
```

**Update 1:**
Also i can't subscribe with `callback` method, i get the message as  `[channel:/meta/subscribe, id:4, subscription:/foo/hello, error:403:denied_by_not_granting:create_denied, successful:false]`.  I don't know what i am doing wrong ? I am just following the documentation steps. Thanks in advance.

Comment: where are you publishing a message?

Comment: @BojanPetkovic at same channel.. but it doesn't matter before that i can't get the subscribed message in client side onMessage.. am i saying correct..?

Comment: Error : 403. means forbidden, likely that topic can only have messages published from accounts, which your listener does not have access to.

You likely cannot get messages in the subscribe part, since no messages were sent.  From your log: "last=0" <- seems to indicate no messages were sent yet.

Comment: @BojanPetkovic Then How to publish & subscribe properly.. it is little confusing ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ClientSessionChannel.MessageListener` that you pass to the `subscribe(...)` method will be invoked whenever a message will be published on channel `/foo/hello`.

Your program never publishes a message on that channel, so the listener is never invoked, therefore in your code `subscribed` is never printed.

You want to double check what version of the `subscribe()` method you want to use, as there are 2 versions.

The [single parameter version](https://docs.cometd.org/current/apidocs/org/cometd/bayeux/client/ClientSessionChannel.html#subscribe-org.cometd.bayeux.client.ClientSessionChannel.MessageListener-) takes a listener, while the [two parameter version](https://docs.cometd.org/current/apidocs/org/cometd/bayeux/client/ClientSessionChannel.html#subscribe-org.cometd.bayeux.client.ClientSessionChannel.MessageListener-org.cometd.bayeux.client.ClientSessionChannel.MessageListener-) takes a listener *and* a callback.

Guessing from your code, you want the `subscribed` log line be in the *callback* not in the listener, so you just need to change your code to use the two parameter version of the `subscribe()` method.

Also, pay attention to the fact that if the JVM exits at the end of your groovy script, then that client will be gone and will never receive any message.

Comment: As you said, Also I tried `subscribe` with callback method. It shows `error:403:denied_by_not_granting:create denied`

Comment: This happens because the CometD demo server restricts the channels a client can publish to, see [this section](https://docs.cometd.org/current/reference/#_java_server_authorizers) of the documentation.  Change the channel in your example from `/foo/hello` to `/chat/hello` and you will succeed.  The authorizers for the demo are defined in [this file](https://github.com/cometd/cometd/blob/3.1.3/cometd-java/cometd-java-examples/src/main/java/org/cometd/examples/ChatService.java).

Comment: sorry for my Late response. Learned . As you said in answer, What is the correct way to keep the Bayeux Client JVM to recieve the published results inside the subscribe